# Numbers that cannot be expressed as fractions

Tags: terminology, fractions, irrational-numbers

What are **Numbers** that cannot be expressed as **Fractions** called?

Comment: Do you mean, what are they called? Irrational. Do you mean, give some examples? $\sqrt2$ and $\pi$. Do you mean something else? Please expand.

Comment: $\sqrt 2 =\frac{2}{\sqrt 2}$

Answer (score 7):

Any number that can be expressed as the **ratio** of integers: (i.e., any number that can be expressed as a *fraction* whose numerator and denominator are both integers), is called a [**rational** number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) (as in "ratio").  Any number that **cannot be expressed** as a ratio of integers (fraction) is called an [**irrational** number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number), as in "not rational".

For example, we have that $2 = \dfrac 21$ is a rational number, as is $0.3\overline{33} = \dfrac 13.\;$ Both numbers are rational numbers because we can express each as equal to a fraction (with integers for numerator and denominator).

On the other hand, $\sqrt 2, \; \pi,\; \dfrac {\sqrt 3}{2}$ are all irrational numbers: none of them can be expressed as a fraction of ***integers***; i.e. there do not exist any integers $p, q, r, s$ such that $\dfrac pq =\sqrt 2$ or such that $\;\pi = \dfrac rs$.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers that can be expressed as a fraction are called *rational*. Numbers that can't be expressed as a fraction are called *irrational*. $\sqrt{2}$ is famously irrational, and so are many numbers like $\pi$, $\sqrt[5]{17}$, $e$, $\ln 2$, and so on. There are lots more irrational numbers than rational numbers, but I'll leave you to look up the proof yourself.

Comment: $\pi$ is irrational but can be expressed as a fraction, $\pi = \dfrac{\pi}{1}$.

Comment: See http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2208#comic